# how can I use highcharts no-data-to-display module as es6-module?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, es6-modules

As the question says, I want to use no-data-to-display as es6-module,but I can't find that module in npm.

Answer (score 1):

First install the npm package;

```
npm install highcharts-no-data-to-display --save
```

and to be able to use it;

```
require('highcharts-no-data-to-display')
```

or

```
<script src = "node_modules/highcharts-no-data-to-display/index.js">
```